# How to apply a patch generated with git format-patch?

Tags: git, patch

I have two local git repositories, both pointing to the *same* remote repository.

In one git repository, if I do `git format-patch 1`, how can I apply that patch to the other repository?

Comment: Related: 1) [What is the difference between `git am` and `git apply`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12240154/4561887), 2) [How to configure and use `git send-email` to work with gmail to email patches to developers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68238912/4561887)

Answer (score 591):

Note: You can first preview what your patch will do:

First the stats:

```
git apply --stat a_file.patch
```

Then a dry run to detect errors:

```
git apply --check a_file.patch
```

Finally, you can use **[`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am)** to apply your patch as a commit. This also allows you to [sign off](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit#Documentation/git-commit.txt---signoff) an applied patch.
This can be useful for later reference.

```
git am --keep-cr --signoff < a_file.patch
```

As noted by [riverofwind](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2537892/riverofwind) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249852/how-to-apply-a-patch-generated-with-git-format-patch/2250170#comment132398023_2250170):

> Don't forget if you have `autocrlf=false` for Windows only development you'll need to pass [`--keep-cr`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am#Documentation/git-am.txt---no-keep-cr) to `am` to keep those CRLFs

See an [example in this article](http://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/):

> In your git log, you’ll find that the commit messages contain a “Signed-off-by” tag. This tag will be read by Github and others to provide useful info about how the commit ended up in the code.

[image: Example]

Comment: `git am < somepatch.patch` yields "fatal: empty ident name (for <>) not allowed". Can someone explain to me why?

Comment: @gromit190 that means bad `Author` headers in the patch, and/or you didn't `git config user.{name,email}`.

Comment: OK; `git apply --check` says `patch does not apply`, and `git apply -3` says `repository lacks the necessary blob to fall back on 3-way merge.` In git, rebasing commits is such a breeze; but how do people **rebase their patches** on top of updated code?

Comment: @ulidtko Maybe with https://stackoverflow.com/a/15375869/6309 ?

Comment: @VonC how can i get back, before to apply the patch?

Comment: Also don't forget if you have autocrlf=false for Windows only development you'll need to pass --keep-cr to am to keep those crlfs

Answer (score 318):

```
git apply name-of-file.patch
```

Comment: This may not have answered the original detailed question but it answered the question in the title which is why I am on this page. thank you!

Comment: I understand this is an old question and answer... but I thought it may be helpful to some people to understand the [difference between git apply and git am](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240154/what-is-the-difference-between-git-am-and-git-apply).

Comment: git apply "[...full path to the file...]/name-of-file.patch"

Answer (score 74):

Or, if you're kicking it old school:

```
cd /path/to/other/repository
patch -p1 < 0001-whatever.patch
```

Comment: Just so you're aware: That won't create a commit, so it will lose commit message and author information.

Comment: I've had some cases where this works when `git apply` doesnt, not sure why

Comment: This is very useful if you are trying to apply a patch to a path or file that is ignored by Git and you have a Git formatted patch.

Comment: Indeed, extremely useful when trying to apply a git generated patch on a machine that does not have git installed (docker images for example)

Comment: Thanks sir! Worked for me when `git apply` just didn't do anything.

Comment: @Dominic. Can you do that in a single line? Like `git commit | patch -p0/1`

Comment: @Amir Sure. Use a pipe. If you need to change directories, etc. in between consider using [named pipes.](https://linuxconfig.org/introduction-to-named-pipes-on-bash-shell)

Answer (score 47):

First you should take a note about [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240235/4632019) between `git am` and `git apply`

When you are using `git am` you usually wanna to apply many patches. Thus should use:

```
git am *.patch
```

or just:

```
git am
```

Git will find patches automatically and apply them in order ;-)

**UPD**
[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52314638/4632019) you can find how to generate such patches

Comment: This explanation of the difference helped me to use `git apply` .. and in `--reverse` :-) 

Comment: Do you happen to know what “am” is supposed to stand for? Maybe “*a*pply en *m*asse”? ;)

Comment: @fitojb, `am` may stand for "apply mail", since patches used to be emailed around a lot. See this comment here: [What is the difference between `git am` and `git apply`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240154/what-is-the-difference-between-git-am-and-git-apply#comment16438444_12240154)

Answer (score 34):

If you want to apply it **as a commit**, use [git am](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html).

Comment: How do you usually get the mbox files in the first place?

Comment: or just use `git apply`

Comment: @Sebi2020 : `git apply` applies changes as a patch, not as a commit, while `git am` assumes that the text of the email is the commit message (with some exceptions) and applies changes creating a commit (and it can try to resolve conflicts with 3-way merge with `git am --3way`.

Comment: I cannot get `git am` to work. It stops in the middle applying changes and the commit generated is incomplete

Comment: @KansaiRobot : there might be a content conflict when applying changes, but there is not enough information in your comment; please post the problem as a question, with as much detail as possible.

Answer (score 27):

If you're using a JetBrains IDE (like IntelliJ IDEA, Android Studio, PyCharm), you can drag the patch file and drop it inside the IDE, and a dialog will appear, showing the patch's content. All you have to do now is to click "Apply patch", and a commit will be created.

Comment: @LasithaBenaragama - kind of. SO is meant to not only help the OP, but also everyone who follows. This answer (while useful) doesn't provide a general solution. This would make an excellent little blog post, but not a "SO good" answer. Would explain the downvote!

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to add one of the local repositories as a remote to another one.

```
$ cd repo1
$ git remote add repo2 file:///path/to/repo2/.git
```

So that you can fetch branches, rebase local branches, or cherry-pick commits from one local repo to another.

```
$ git remote update repo2
$ git fetch repo2 branch:branch-from-repo2
$ git log branch-from-repo2
```