# How to use git am to apply patches from email messages?

Tags: git

I am pretty familiar with git(the basic stuff atleast-branches, merges,collaboration with peers etc.) but the other day a friend of mine told me that we could use git with our mailbox.
The command involved is `git am` ([manual page here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am)).

Please could someone help me get started with `git am`.

Comment: Are you on unix/linux or Windows? and will you actually use email, or do you have a network connection that could exchange patch files?

Comment: A complete answer might depend on 1) which email client you use 2) if you are subscribed to the mailing list where patches are sent, or not 3) the mailing list archive software used by the project..

Answer (score 27):

The other big thing involved is [`git format-patch`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-format-patch.html). This will create the patches to be emailed; they can then be sent using [`git send-email`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-send-email.html) or directly. For example:

```
# create a patch for each commit from origin's master to yours
git format-patch origin/master..master

# now send them... 
# there are a zillion options here, and also some configuration; read the man page
git send-email --to=maintainer@project.com --from=me@here.com ... *.patch
```

[`git am`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-am.html) will accept the patches created by `format-patch`, and apply them sequentially, for example:

```
git am *.patch
```

You'll have to figure out how to export the patches in mbox format from your mail client yourself, though I suppose you could also simply send them as attachments or transfer them directly.

You can try this out for yourself entirely within one repository to see how it works. Create a set of patches as above, then check out the starting point, and use `git am` to apply the patches.

Comment: would i be able to run this from a hotmail or a gmail account? if so how?

Comment: @DarkKnight: On which end? There are instructions for using gmail as the smtp server for `git send-email` in the manpage. On the other end... if the patches were sent as attachments, just save them all and apply exactly as I explained in my answer. If they're sent in-line, you can (in gmail) show the original message (dropdown at the top right), save it, delete the blank line at the top (not sure where that comes from), and run `git am` on it.

Comment: What client do you use to get messages in mbox format?

Comment: Note that `git am *.patch` does not work with Windows command prompt. Be sure to use bash when running that command. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/60097534/468215

Answer (score 5):

**Patchwork workaround**

https://github.com/getpatchwork/patchwork

Since no one seems to know how to convert emails to mbox with readily available tools, many of those cornerstone dinosaur projects projects have an associated, sometimes officially recommended, patchwork instance running, many of them hosted on https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/ e.g.:

- https://patchwork.sourceware.org/project/gdb/list/ GDB, mentioned on the official contribution guidelines: https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/ContributionChecklist#Patch_status
- https://patchwork.kernel.org/ Linux kernel
- https://patchwork.kernel.org/project/git/list/ Git
- https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/qemu-devel/list/ QEMU
- https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/gcc/list/ GCC
- https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/glibc/list/ glibc

Patchwork subscribes to the list, and parses the patches generated by `git send-email`, and allows you to download a patch.

So yes, yet another tooling layer on top of email...

**Thunderbird export to mbox**

Asked at: [What is the easiest way to apply git series of patches from Thunderbird](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7794772/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-apply-git-series-of-patches-from-thunderbird) No answer so far.

**See also**

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80519/how-do-i-get-a-linux-kernel-patch-set-from-the-mailing-list
- [How to apply a patch generated with git format-patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249852/how-to-apply-a-patch-generated-with-git-format-patch)

Comment: This tip is great.  I found the Patchwork download as mbox feature and `git am /path/to/download.patch` command very useful.

Comment: You write "GCC, which includes GDB", but I do not see any GDB patches there... maybe it used to be there, but not anymore ?

Comment: @philb Hmm, I don't remember anymore, I've updated with what seems to be the correct one now, thanks for this.

Answer (score 4):

You need a mail client that can export mail as mbox file.  Export the mails and run `git-am your-mbox-file`. It's done.

Answer (score 2):

If the mailing list for the project you want to apply patches from uses [public-inbox](https://public-inbox.org/README.html), which is the case for [most Linux subprojects and Git](https://lore.kernel.org/lists.html), you can use [`b4 am`](https://pypi.org/project/b4/) tool to download the most recent version of a patch series and pipe it to `git am`:

```sh
b4 am -o- $url | git am
```

where `url` is the URL of any message in the thread.