# How to download and apply a patch from gdb mailing list to gdb using git

Tags: git, gdb, patch

I just want to apply a patch to gdb source code from gdb patch mailing list, but I dont know how to download the particular patch. The patch seems to contain a lot of messages along with the output of "diff" program so I am a bit confused and need help. I will prefer to use "git apply" for applying the patch once I download it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applying git patches from a mailing list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24856020/applying-git-patches-from-a-mailing-list)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the patch on sourceware.org in the mailing list archives, there is a "raw text" link.  Download using that link.

That might be sufficient.

Depending on the patch it might already be in a git repository somewhere.  You can ask the author.  That's far simpler.