# How to add branched changes only in Git?

Tags: git

I had an initial project with some unstaged changes. I added a new branch & made some more changes to the project. How do I add files to the staging area with changes I made in that specific branch only? I can manually add each file using **git add** but I'd like to know if its possible.

Comment: are the changes committed on the branch, or they are also on the staging area ?

Comment: @Mellowcandle They are on the staging area

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unstaged changes do not belong to any branch. Thus, creating/switching branches while you have unstaged changes carries those changes over to the new branch as if you had made the changes after you switched branches.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best thing, is to create a patch of the changes currently staged, and then apply this patch over in the other branch.
You can follow the instruction of creating a patch of staged changes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159185/create-a-git-patch-from-the-changes-in-the-current-working-directory)