# Move all new code on Master to a new branch in Git

Tags: git, branch

I'm using Git. I accidentally started doing all of my code changes on Master. How can I create a branch "new_feature" and have all of my changes moved to the "new_feature" branch and off of master?

Comment: Did you commit your changes?  If not then just git branch new_feature and commit to that.  If you've commited then do the same and use git log to find the version master was at before you started making changes and git checkout <version hash> to get it back to that state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't committed yet to the master branch. do a `git diff` to create a patch.
create new branch

`git checkout -b new_branch`

and apply the patches using `git apply`

You can follow this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159185/create-a-git-patch-from-the-changes-in-the-current-working-directory) in order to understand better how to create patches from uncommited / unstaged changes

Answer (score 3):

If you've already committed your code, you need to only run `git checkout -b new_feature`. This will both create your new branch and switch you to that new branch.

If you have not yet committed your changes, run `git checkout -b new_feature` then commit your changes.

If after creating your new branch and committing your code, you need to revert your master branch:

```
git checkout master              # switch to the master branch
git reset --hard origin/master   # revert master to the current origin/master
```

Be aware that `git reset --hard` will cause you to lose any uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
% git commit ...               # save any untracked changes
% git branch <new-branch>      # created a branch, but you're still on master
% git log                      # find the first development commit
% git reset --hard "<commit>^" # set the master branch to before the commit
% git checkout <new-branch>    # recommence your development work
% git checkout master          # return to work prior to development
```

Be careful with `reset --hard`, as you can lose untracked changes.  Also, do not `reset --hard` beyond a commit that has already been pushed to the remote.

Answer (score 2):

If you haven't committed your changes just switch to a new branch:

```
git checkout -b new_features
```

This will take all your changes to the new branch without effecting master branch. Here you can commit all your changes.