# How to create patch using git and apply it as well

Tags: git

I have an untracked file with some changes. Its called file1.

I want to apply those changes to my tracked file in git, called file2.

Is there a way using git that I can get the patch and apply it to my tracked file , file2?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but:  you have a file that's untracked locally, and it has changes that you want to incorporate into your tracked file locally, right?  Why not use `git add <file>` instead?  Why do you want to create a patch file?

Comment: @makoto I just edited my question to make it more clear.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create a git patch from the changes in the current working directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159185/create-a-git-patch-from-the-changes-in-the-current-working-directory)

Answer (score 0):

By definition, if your files are untracked, Git does not know about their history. You can use `git diff` to get the difference between two files, and `git apply` to apply a patch, but this all makes sense only once you have two states (before changes, after changes).