# Where does git keep the local repository stashed file?

Tags: git

I would like to sym link to the directory containing the stashed files.

If there are multiple stash items in the stash list of the local repository then I would like to zip them all from a sym link.

Comment: `stashed files` that may be a problem. Stashes are stored as commits which generally looks like a diff patch instead of a bunch of files

Comment: So they are stored as commits, but are not showed by the `git status` nor `git log` commands ?

Comment: What I meant was that their structure is the same as a commit. I didn't mean they were stored in the same log. The reason for using the same structure is because when you pop a stash all the merge management code must also work on the stashed commit like they do with real commits you pull from remote

Comment: If you want to ship the patches, this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159185/create-a-git-patch-from-the-changes-in-the-current-working-directory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The stash is actually stored as a commit sha and can be viewed in

```
./logs/refs/stash
./refs/stash
```

Then you could `git show` the commit sha or append `--name-status` to it to view the list of files in stash.

Comment: I only have this file `less ./.git/refs/stash` and it only contains a sha. Where is the actual content then ?

Comment: Its stored as a blob. You could git show <commit_sha> to see the actual content

Comment: A blob is a binay large object. I'm not sure that is the case with stash content.

Comment: Since a stash is stored as a commit sha itself, its likely to be stored the same way as any other commit. https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: A stash is in fact at least *two*, and sometimes three, commits. See, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/q/20586009/1256452 for details.