# How to apply changes in any version of code in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, patch, openedx

I have made some changes in some file of openEdX source code. Now I want to create a patch such that it can be applied to new versions of that file.
How should I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The openedx source code is managed by git, so you only need to create a regular git patch.

[This is solved in some other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5159185/2072496)

The short answer would be to do a `cd /edx/app/edxapp/edx-platform` and then

```
git diff > mypatch.patch
```

Comment: what if some new version comes and instead of going through the code I just want to apply that patch. Will it work? I don't think so because line numbers would have changes now.

Comment: The line number can have changes in other places of the file. As long as git can still apply the patch and no conflicts arise, this will work. If the file changed exactly where the patch is being applied, then the cli will tell you about the conflict