# "You are not currently on a branch" error when trying to sync fork with upstream repository

Tags: git, github, rebase, git-fork

I made [a fork of a GitHub repository](https://github.com/BioGeek/biopython). I fixed [a bug](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/issues/1402), wrote a test and created [a pull request](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/1429) which was [merged](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/commit/1a32c50fb91b9461eb4c0d0d427823dca81b41ee) into the original repository.

So far, so good.

Now I improved the test on my local machine. I want to create a new pull request with this improved test. But in the meantime, other commits have been made to the original, upstream repository. So I want to get my fork into sync with the upstream repository so that I can create the new pull request.

Without fully grasping what I was doing, I've been copy/pasting git commands from other StackOverflow answers. But I can't get it to work.

Here is what the situation currently looks like:

```
$ git push
fatal: You are not currently on a branch.
To push the history leading to the current (detached HEAD)
state now, use

    git push origin HEAD:<name-of-remote-branch>
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto 4378fa4
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on '4378fa4'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        Tests/.vscode/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

Or visually:

```
$ git log --all --graph --pretty=format:'%C(auto)%h%C(auto)%d %s %C(dim white)(%aN, %ar)'
* 46f5c0e (HEAD) Change to non-UTF8 locale C (ASCII only) inside test (BioGeek, 3 hours ago)
| *   fe24176 (master) merge changes from upstream (BioGeek, 3 days ago)
| |\
| |/
|/|
* | 4378fa4 (upstream/master) Thank Jerven for ExPASy URL updates (Peter Cock, 3 days ago)
* | 03de45c Update ExPASy tests for HTTPS (Peter Cock, 3 days ago)
* | 47cdbf7 Move expasy URLs to https (Jerven Bolleman, 4 days ago)
* | 9bfb8b1 replace expasy.ch by expasy.org (Jerven Bolleman, 4 days ago)
* | 1a32c50 Determine encoding for urllib handles from HTTP headers (Jeroen Van Goey, 3 days ago)
* | ccf88fc Tests do not require postgresql CREATE DATABASE permissions (Adhemar Zerlotini, 3 days ago)
| | *   6b7d235 (refs/stash) WIP on master: 6311677 remove Doc/examples/tree1.nwk which was committed accidentally (created during testing?) (BioGeek, 3 days ago)
| | |\
| |/ /
| | * 4ead5fa index on master: 6311677 remove Doc/examples/tree1.nwk which was committed accidentally (created during testing?) (BioGeek, 3 days ago)
| |/
| * 6311677 (origin/master, origin/HEAD) remove Doc/examples/tree1.nwk which was committed accidentally (created during testing?) (BioGeek, 3 days ago)
| * 41ff4cc Address flake8 warnings (BioGeek, 3 days ago)
| * 815bbfd Add encoding and prefic unicode string with 'u' (BioGeek, 3 days ago)
| * 0e7451d If the handle has a headers attribute, then use it's content charset as encoding. Otherwise fall back to the default behaviour. (BioGeek, 4 days ago)
| * 6a7d05b Add test for correct handling of encodings in Entrez.efetch. Also add some missing docstrings in other tests and close handles everywhere (BioGeek, 4 days ago)
|/
* 4ccdace mmCIF parser fix to check for both '?' and '.' as unassigned values (Joao Rodrigues, 5 days ago)
```

Changeset `46f5c0e` is the improved test from which I want to create a new pull request.

How do I get to sync my fork with the upstream repository so that I can create the new pull request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in git's somewhat helpful error message:

```
$ git status
rebase in progress; onto 4378fa4
You are currently rebasing branch 'master' on '4378fa4'.
  (all conflicts fixed: run "git rebase --continue")
```

## Continue rebasing

This means you have probably `git pull -r` from your upstream, or are rebasing a branch onto another branch locally, *and* you have encountered a problem while attempting to automatically merge (likely a merge conflict).

When git encounters a merge conflict while attempting to fast-foward, it stops rebasing and waits for the user fix the problem manually.

Once that is done, you need to stage the changed files you fixed (with `git add <pathspec>`) but not make a commit. Once the file is staged, git will be aware of your changes and attempt to integrate them when you `git rebase --continue`.

Keep fixing problems and `git rebase --continue` until you are done. This will move your HEAD to the tip of your working branch. You can then push.

## Alternatively

You can `git rebase --abort` to abandon the whole thing, which will also undo any fixes you have made along the way, and try another merge strategy, like a 3-way merge.

One advantage of a three-way merge over a fast-forward is that all of the merge conflicts will be presented at the same time and you can create a new merge commit with all the fixes. While fast-forwarding, however, you may need to stop several times to fix conflicts as git encounters them while applying successive commits to your working branch.

## My personal take

Given

> Without fully grasping what I was doing, I've been copy/pasting git commands from other StackOverflow answers. But I can't get it to work.

I would `git rebase --abort` and start from scratch. If you stopped many times and had to fix many merge conflicts, you could use `git pull --no-ff <remote-name> <local-branch>` to explicitly instruct git not to try a fast forward, even if it can.

## Last-ditch option

If the histories are just unmanageable and your change is small, you can always "shelve" your changes, meaning copy your version of the changed files to your desktop [and then overwrite your local branch with the exact content of the upstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8888015/114900). Then, just copy the changed files back into your repo and make a commit.

It is not an elegant solution, but it works and is sometimes far easier than managing a long history. But you will lose the commits you had. There is a way to [preserve them with patching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5159185/create-a-git-patch-from-the-changes-in-the-current-working-directory), if you're really interested.

## Further Reading

More on what [detatched HEAD means](https://www.git-tower.com/learn/git/faq/detached-head-when-checkout-commit).

Comment: Thanks, for the detailed answer! I have some reading to do so that I better understand what I'm doing, but I'll follow your advice of doing `git rebase --abort`.

Comment: @BioGeek My pleasure. I'm taking a couple of minutes to read [your fork](https://github.com/BioGeek/biopython) and see that your histories have indeed diverged `This branch is 7 commits ahead, 17 commits behind biopython:master.` A rebase is usually the appropriate solution. Perhaps just abort and try it again *with fast forward* (so `git pull -r <upstream-name> master`) from a fresh start, fix conflicts, continue, and push. Then you can compare branches with biopython and see if it looks good.

Comment: @BioGeek As an aside, I have taken the habit both at my day job and in OS contributions to pull from upstream basically every time I sit down to start working in order to ensure the potential quantity of merge conflicts is manageable. Not always necessary at that frequency, but handy to do.

Comment: I managed to make the [pull request](https://github.com/biopython/biopython/pull/1434)! It still wasn't perfect (the git commit history gave merge conflicts), but we're making progress. :-)

Comment: @BioGeek Glad to hear it! My first few public PRs were a _complete_ mess, you're doing quite well. Git branching allows you to make test branches and do whatever you want with impunity, so just keep experimenting.