# Bump version and publish packages from one branch but keep tags in another branch

Tags: npm, lerna

I'm migrating my project consisting of many dependent on each other packages to monorepo with [Lerna](https://lernajs.io/). We follow something like [Gitflow workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) during development. The main concept is to make all source code changes in `develop` branch and all other branches (feature, bugfix, etc.) created from and merged back to `develop`. As long as new version of a package is ready we publish it by `npm publish` or `yarn publish` and then merge it to `master` branch and tag it there manually the following way:

```sh
$ git checkout develop
```

Make some changes in source code including version bumping...

```sh
$ git add -A
$ git commit -m "Make some changes and version bump."
$ git checkout master
$ git merge --no-ff develop -m "Version 0.14.1."
$ git tag -a 0.14.1 -m "Version 0.14.1."
```

Now I want to achieve the same thing managing all the packages with Lerna. Looking at the docs I stated that [publish](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/publish) command relies on [version](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/version) command that, in turn, uses [changed](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/changed) command behind the scenes to detect changes made in packages since latest release:

> List local packages that have changed since the last tagged release

Consider that some change is made in `develop` branch in one package (say, `@geoapps/layout`)

[image]

```sh
$ lerna changed
```

says that all packages are changed (that is not that I expect):

```
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.13.1
lerna info Assuming all packages changed
@geoapps/angle
@geoapps/camera-scene-mode-switcher
...
@geoapps/tracer
@geoapps/vector
lerna success found 39 packages ready to publish
```

I guess that it happens due to Lerna looks for tagged commits in `develop` branch to compare with but nothing is found there. If I commit source code changes to `master` branch

[image]

then Lerna detects them in single `@geoapps/layout` package properly:

```sh
$ git checkout master
$ lerna changed
```

```
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.13.1
lerna info Looking for changed packages since 0.14.1
@geoapps/layout
lerna success found 1 package ready to publish
```

But making changes in `master` branch is also not what I want to do. [include-merged-tags](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/tree/master/commands/version#--include-merged-tags) was another option I tried to use but seems it works only when tagged commit is also a part of the history of `develop` branch:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git merge --no-ff master -m "Sync with master."
```

[image]

```sh
$ lerna changed --include-merged-tags
```

```
info cli using local version of lerna
lerna notice cli v3.13.1
lerna info Looking for changed packages since 0.14.1
@geoapps/layout
lerna success found 1 package ready to publish
```

Since all source code changes tagged in `master` branch are present in `develop` branch I wonder whether it is possible to force Lerna to compare changes made in `develop` branch not with tagged commits from `master` but with their parent commits (`0.14.1^2`) also belonging to `develop`. Is it possible?

Environment:

```
$ node --version
v10.15.0
$ npm --version
6.9.0
$ yarn --version
1.15.2
$ lerna --version
3.13.1
```

Comment: Posted the same question/feature request on [GitHub](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2023).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Lerna's core developer [says](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/issues/2023#issuecomment-480402592) that Lerna doesn't suit well to work with Gitflow workflow. To say more, it's [prohibited](https://github.com/lerna/lerna/pull/2024) to publish packages detecting their changes from specific commit (tagged commit in another branch). Latest tagged release should belong to the same branch where changes were made.

Keeping it and our wish to stay with Gitflow in mind I decided to patch Lerna to achieve the desired behavior. Just [created git patch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15438863/506695) and placed it in the root directory of my project using Lerna.

**lerna-version-since.patch**

```
diff --git a/commands/version/command.js b/commands/version/command.js
index da9b1c00..3c5e19e2 100644
--- a/commands/version/command.js
+++ b/commands/version/command.js
@@ -104,6 +104,11 @@ exports.builder = (yargs, composed) => {
       requiresArg: true,
       defaultDescription: "alpha",
     },
+    since: {
+      describe: "Look for changes since specified commit instead of last tagged release",
+      type: "string",
+      requiresArg: true,
+    },
     "sign-git-commit": {
       describe: "Pass the `--gpg-sign` flag to `git commit`.",
       type: "boolean",
```

If something changes in `commands/version/command.js` then we will probably update the patch. In order to apply the patch one should run this command:

```sh
$ git apply -p3 --directory node_modules/@lerna/version lerna-version-since.patch
```

Having patched Lerna it's now possible to bump and publish in `develop` branch and tag a release in `master`. In order to make things simplier I wrote a script called `lerna-gitflow.js` that makes everything automatically. Here is a script section of `package.json`:

```
"scripts": {
  "publish:major": "./lerna-gitflow.js publish major",
  "publish:minor": "./lerna-gitflow.js publish minor",
  "publish:patch": "./lerna-gitflow.js publish patch",
  "changes": "./lerna-gitflow.js changes",
  "postinstall": "./lerna-gitflow.js patch"
}
```

All these `publish:*` and `changes` commands should be run from development branch (`develop` by default).

`changes` command just shows changed packages in development branch (`develop`) since latest release tag in release branch (`master` by default).

`publish` command does two things:

- updates versions in `package.json` files of changed packages, in root `package.json` and `lerna.json` and commits them to `develop` branch locally (it can be done separately by running, for example, `./lerna-gitflow.js version patch`);
- publishes changed packages to npm registry from `develop` branch, then merges changes to `master` branch without fast-forward and tag a new release there (it also can be done separately by running `./lerna-gitflow.js publish --skip-version`).

`postinstall` script tries to patch Lerna on any `npm install` or `yarn install` call otherwise required changes to make everything working will be lost.

**lerna-gitflow.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
const path = require('path');
const yargs = require('yargs');
const execa = require('execa');
const jsonfile = require('jsonfile');

const noop = () => {};

async function lernaCommand(command, options) {
  const { devBranch } = options;
  const branch = await getCurrentBranch();
  if (branch !== devBranch) {
    return Promise.reject(
      `You should be in "${devBranch}" branch to detect changes but current branch is "${branch}".`
    );
  }
  const latestVersion = await getLatestVersion();

  const bumpVersion = async bump => {
    await lernaVersion(latestVersion, bump);
    const version = await getLernaVersion();
    const packageJsonPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'package.json');
    const packageJson = await jsonfile.readFile(packageJsonPath);
    packageJson.version = version;
    await jsonfile.writeFile(packageJsonPath, packageJson, { spaces: 2 });
    await exec('git', ['add', '-A']);
    await exec('git', ['commit', '-m', 'Version bump.']);
    return version;
  };

  const reject = e => {
    if (typeof e === 'string') {
      return Promise.reject(e);
    }
    return Promise.reject('Unable to detect any changes in packages, probably nothing has changed.');
  };

  switch (command) {
    case 'publish': {
      const { bump, skipVersion, releaseBranch } = options;
      if (releaseBranch === devBranch) {
        return Promise.reject('Release and development branches can\'t be the same.');
      }
      try {
        const version = skipVersion ? await getLernaVersion() : await bumpVersion(bump);
        await lernaPublish(latestVersion, version);
        await exec('git', ['checkout', releaseBranch]);
        await exec('git', ['merge', '--no-ff', devBranch, '-m', `Version ${version}.`]);
        await exec('git', ['tag', '-a', version, '-m', `Version ${version}.`]);
        await exec('git', ['checkout', devBranch]);
      }
      catch (e) {
        return reject(e);
      }
      break;
    }

    case 'version': {
      const { bump } = options;
      try {
        await bumpVersion(bump);
      }
      catch (e) {
        return reject(e);
      }
      break;
    }

    case 'changed': {
      try {
        await lernaChanged(latestVersion);
      }
      catch (e) {
        return reject(e);
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}

async function lernaPublish(since, version) {
  if (since === version) {
    return Promise.reject(`Unable to publish packages with same version ${version}.`);
  }
  return exec('lerna', ['publish', '--since', since, version, '--no-push', '--no-git-tag-version', '--yes']);
}

async function lernaVersion(since, bump) {
  return exec('lerna', ['version', '--since', since, bump, '--no-push', '--no-git-tag-version', '--yes']);
}

async function lernaChanged(since) {
  return exec('lerna', ['changed', '--since', since]);
}

async function patch() {
  try {
    await exec('git', ['apply', '-p3', '--directory', 'node_modules/@lerna/version', 'lerna-version-since.patch']);
  }
  catch (e) {
    return Promise.reject('Lerna Gitflow patch is not applied (probably, it\'s already applied before).');
  }
}

async function getCurrentBranch() {
  const { stdout } = await exec('git', ['branch']);
  const match = stdout.match(/\* ([\S]+)/);
  if (match === null) {
    return Promise.reject('Unable to detect current git branch.');
  }
  return match[1];
}

async function getLatestTaggedCommit() {
  const { stdout } = await exec('git', ['rev-list', '--tags', '--max-count', 1]);
  if (!stdout) {
    return Promise.reject('Unable to find any tagged commit.');
  }
  return stdout;
}

async function getLatestVersion() {
  const commit = await getLatestTaggedCommit();
  const { stdout } = await exec('git', ['describe', '--tags', commit]);
  return stdout;
}

async function getLernaVersion() {
  const lernaJson = await jsonfile.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'lerna.json'));
  return lernaJson.version;
}

function exec(cmd, args, opts) {
  console.log(`$ ${cmd} ${args.join(' ')}`);
  const promise = execa(cmd, args, opts);
  promise.stdout.pipe(process.stdout);
  promise.stderr.pipe(process.stderr);
  return promise;
}

yargs
  .wrap(null)
  .strict(true)
  .help(true, 'Show help')
  .version(false)
  .fail((msg, error) => {
    console.error(error);
    if (msg) {
      console.error(msg);
    }
  })
  .demandCommand()
  .command(
    'publish <bump>',
    'Bump and commit packages\' in development branch, then publish, merge into and tag in release branch',
    yargs => yargs
      .positional('bump', {
        describe: 'Type of version update',
        type: 'string'
      })
      .option('skip-version', {
        describe: 'Skip version bumping and commiting in development branch',
        type: 'boolean',
        default: false
      }),
    opts => lernaCommand('publish', opts)
  )
  .command(
    'version <bump>',
    'Bump and commit packages\' version in development branch',
    yargs => yargs
      .positional('bump', {
        describe: 'Type of version update',
        type: 'string'
      }),
    opts => lernaCommand('version', opts)
  )
  .command(
    'changes',
    'Detect packages changes since latest release',
    noop,
    opts => lernaCommand('changed', opts)
  )
  .command('patch', 'Patch Lerna to use with Gitflow', noop, () => patch())
  .options({
    'dev-branch': {
      describe: 'Name of git development branch',
      type: 'string',
      demandOption: true,
      default: 'develop'
    },
    'release-branch': {
      describe: 'Name of git release branch',
      type: 'string',
      demandOption: true,
      default: 'master'
    }
  })
  .parse();
```