# How can I instruct git diff NOT to batch together hunks that are near by?

Tags: git, diff

Essentially, I would like `git diff` to return the same hunks as returned when I chose to split the hunks in an interactive rebase.

The command I am using is:

```
git diff -U3 -r -M
```

And it can produce something like this:

```
@@ -70,10 +70,10 @@
   "GetAllDeptJobs2": "None",
   "GetAllDeptJobsSlim": "None",
   "GetAllDirectDeposits": "Payroll (*)",
-  "GetAllEmployeeBenPlanElectedOptions": "None",
+  "GetAllEmployeeBenPlanElectedOptions": "Benefits (*)",
   "GetAllEmployeeConfidentialIdentifications": "HR (*)",
-  "GetAllEmployeeDeductionBenElectedRates": "None",
-  "GetAllEmployeeEarningBenElectedRates": "None",
+  "GetAllEmployeeDeductionBenElectedRates": "Benefits (*)",
+  "GetAllEmployeeEarningBenElectedRates": "Benefits (*)",
   "GetAllEmployeeElectedBenefitBeneficiary": "None",
   "GetAllEmployeeElectedBenefitBeneficiaryAndDependentData": "None",
   "GetAllEmployeeElectedBenefitBeneficiarySL": "None",
```

The relevant portion of the respective file (after the change is applied) is:

```
  "GetAllDeptJobs2": "None",
  "GetAllDeptJobsSlim": "None",
  "GetAllDirectDeposits": "Payroll (*)",
  "GetAllEmployeeBenPlanElectedOptions": "Benefits (*)",
  "GetAllEmployeeConfidentialIdentifications": "HR (*)",
  "GetAllEmployeeDeductionBenElectedRates": "Benefits (*)",
  "GetAllEmployeeEarningBenElectedRates": "Benefits (*)",
  "GetAllEmployeeElectedBenefitBeneficiary": "None",
  "GetAllEmployeeElectedBenefitBeneficiaryAndDependentData": "None",
  "GetAllEmployeeElectedBenefitBeneficiarySL": "None",
```

I would like to get a diff where these two hunks are split. I realize the trailing context of the first hunk overlaps with the delta of the second hunk, but so what? I would like to get the following two hunks instead:

```
@@ -70,7 +70,7 @@
   "GetAllDeptJobs2": "None",
   "GetAllDeptJobsSlim": "None",
   "GetAllDirectDeposits": "Payroll (*)",
-  "GetAllEmployeeBenPlanElectedOptions": "None",
+  "GetAllEmployeeBenPlanElectedOptions": "Benefits (*)",
   "GetAllEmployeeConfidentialIdentifications": "HR (*)",
   "GetAllEmployeeDeductionBenElectedRates": "None",
   "GetAllEmployeeEarningBenElectedRates": "None",
```

And

```
@@ -72,10 +72,10 @@
   "GetAllDirectDeposits": "Payroll (*)",
   "GetAllEmployeeBenPlanElectedOptions": "None",
   "GetAllEmployeeConfidentialIdentifications": "HR (*)",
-  "GetAllEmployeeDeductionBenElectedRates": "None",
-  "GetAllEmployeeEarningBenElectedRates": "None",
+  "GetAllEmployeeDeductionBenElectedRates": "Benefits (*)",
+  "GetAllEmployeeEarningBenElectedRates": "Benefits (*)",
   "GetAllEmployeeElectedBenefitBeneficiary": "None",
   "GetAllEmployeeElectedBenefitBeneficiaryAndDependentData": "None",
   "GetAllEmployeeElectedBenefitBeneficiarySL": "None",
```

I understand why `git diff` batched the two hunks, but is it still possible to get them separately and be able to apply the patch successfully?

Comment: Not really, no - `git diff` always generates a unified diff. You could set the number of context lines to zero with `-U0`; that's as close as you'll get to "yes". To get a non-unified context diff, use the non-Git diff utility included with your OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this is not directly supported by [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) (may `U1` would work?), it is with [`git add -p` (`--patch`)](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add#Documentation/git-add.txt--p)

By typing '`s`' for '`split`' ("[split the current hunk into smaller hunks](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d3fa443f97e3a8d75b51341e2d5bac380b7422df/add-patch.c#L1373-L1380)"), you will get two hunks instead of one, and will be able to apply your first set of changes, without applying the second.

From there, you can [generate a patch from your staged changes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15438863/6309).

```
git diff --cached > mypatch.patch
```

It will include only the first hunk.

Comment: So this is an interactive procedure. Any way to make it non interactive? Besides piping responses, which one should know beforehand.

Comment: @mark Not that I know of: at some point, the diff tool needs a manual input on how small to go.

Comment: to me `s` is for `split`, but `smaller` also works ;-), as per comment in the help `s - split the current hunk into smaller hunks`

Comment: @Julien You are right! I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

`git diff -U0` seems to work for me (`-U1` doesn't).