# What is the difference between git am and git apply?

Tags: git, patch

Both [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) and [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) can be used to apply patches.

It seems that `git am` automatically commits, whereas `git apply` only touches the files but doesn't create a commit. Is that the only difference?

Comment: `am` could be thought of as an abbreviation of `Apply Mail`...

Answer (score 237, accepted):

Both the input and output are different:

- [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) takes a patch (e.g. the output of [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)) and applies it to the working directory (or index, if `--index` or `--cached` is used).
- [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) takes a mailbox of commits formatted as email messages (e.g. the output of [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/format-patch)) and applies them to the current branch.

[`git am` uses `git apply` behind the scenes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bbcefff/git-am.sh#L151), but does more work before (reading a `Maildir` or `mbox`, and parsing email messages) and after (creating commits).

Comment: Note: `git apply` seems to also accept `git format-patch` output.

Comment: `git apply` would work for output from `git format-patch` as well but the changes would be unstaged and would need to be committed (thus creating a different commit point in the index they are applied to). With `git am` you would be carrying the commit information (along with author, etc.) into the index it is applied to.
`git apply` then is for patching your repo (bad), `git am` can take legit feature changes and include it into your repo (preferred approach).

Comment: Which of these would I normally want if I used `GITK` to view my tree and then made a patch from the context menu on my uncommitted changes? I can't imagine git am would work very well if there's no commit information for it to create the commits, so I would guess git apply is what I want.… <br>
…I guess, both in the name of general prudence and because of the moderation strike (My trust for this site is running a little low right now, if they don't understand the problem with AI answers), I should http://www.tryitands.ee

Comment: looks like git apply is the command to do, in the situation I described above. I would assume the same applies if I create the patch from a sequence of commands in GITK? but I don't need to know right now, so I'm not going to try it and see. Feel free to do so yourself!

Answer (score 28):

`git apply` is for applying straight diffs (e.g. from `git diff`) whereas `git am` is for applying patches and sequences of patches from emails, either mbox or Maildir format and is the "opposite" of `git format-patch`. `git am` tries to extract commit messages and author details from email messages which is why it can make commits.

Answer (score 23):

With `git am` you apply the patch so when you run `git status` you won't see any local changes, but `git log` will show the patch have been committed to the source code.

But with `git apply` you make the changes in the source files as if you were writing the code yourself, consequently `git status` and `git diff` will output the changes appeared in the patch you applied. Hence with `git apply` you can fix/add more changes and `git add` them together as a single new patch.

Answer (score 1):

### Quick summary

| Command | Applies Patch? | Creates Commit? | Use Case |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `git apply` | Yes | No | Testing `git diff` patches before committing. Can also be used to apply patches to 3rd-party libraries just before building. |
| `git am` | Yes | Yes | Applying patches from an email or `git format-patch` file. Useful for collaborating and accepting someone else's contributions. |

### Details

1. **`git apply`**: I think to myself: "git apply patch". It reads the supplied `git diff` ("patch") output and applies it to files with*out* creating a commit. Useful for testing a patch before committing it to the repository.

   Official documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply

   > Reads the supplied diff output (i.e. "a patch") and applies it to files.

   > This command applies the patch but does not create a commit. Use [`git-am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) to create commits from patches generated by [`git-format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) and/or received by email.
2. **`git am`**: I think to myself: "git apply (and commit) mail". It is the reverse of `git format-patch`. It takes a file created by `git format-patch`, which is generally a patch emailed to you, and applies it to your repository while also creating a commit. Useful for applying patches from email or files. Can be applied to many "mailed" patches at once via `git am *.patch` ([one source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52418860/4561887)).

   Official documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am

   > Splits mail messages in a mailbox into commit log messages, authorship information, and patches, and applies them to the current branch. You could think of it as a reverse operation of [`git-format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) run on a branch with a straight history without merges.

### See also

1. [How to apply a patch generated with git format-patch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2249852/4561887)
2. My Q&A: [How to configure and use `git send-email` to work with gmail to email patches to developers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68238912/4561887)

In addition to the resources above, I also had some very useful and productive chats with GitHub Copilot about the topic. This answer is my own.