# Git apply vs am

Tags: git

I generated a patch using the following command

`git log -p -m -1 --pretty=email --first-parent XXXX`.

I'd like to apply this patch to another repository (having the same files but not necessarily the same history).

When using `git apply` the patch is correctly applied, except that I have to commit the files myself with the right user, date ...

When using `git am` I have the following errors:

> error: toto.cpp: patch does not apply

I just don't manage to understand why it would work with `apply` but no with `am`

Any idea how I can apply it with `am` ?

Edit:
The answers given in linked answer just explain that `apply` won't commit the changes while `am` will. More it says that `am` uses `apply` in background so it seems it's something specific to the `am` command that fails.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between git am and git apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240154/what-is-the-difference-between-git-am-and-git-apply)

Comment: Actually i looked at this already but I don't think it helps to figure out one would fail while the other succeeds.

Comment: I don't have the time right now to fashion this into a proper answer, but create your patch with `git format-patch` instead, and then you will be able to apply it with either `git am` or `git apply`. `git am` will make commits that look like the originals (with the same author etc.), where as `git apply` will just make local changes, that you could then commit as yourself if you choose to do so

Comment: I also tried to use `format-patch` but the point is that I didn't manage to obtain the same result than `log -p -m -1 --first-parent` to generate patches of merges. If you know the equivalent with `format-patch` i'm interrested :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `git am` command is deliberately picky about its input format *so that* it can create a new commit whose hash ID is *identical to* the hash ID of the original commit, which in turn means that the new commit that `git am` created is bit-for-bit identical to the original commit.

The `git apply` command is deliberately not-so-picky about its input format because *you*, not `git apply`, will create a new commit that is *not* bit-for-bit identical to any original commit.

Your question starts with the command:

```
git log -p -m -1 --pretty=email --first-parent
```

which suggests that you are showing a merge.  The `git format-patch` command never includes merges in its output, because `git am` cannot make merges.  Since the point of `git am` is to make a bit-for-bit identical commit, while the point of `git format-patch` is to produce output suitable for input to `git am` and `git am` cannot make merges, there's no need for `git format-patch` to present a merge commit.

These combine to make the `git am` tool useless for your particular purpose (which appears to be *convert a merge commit to a changeset against its first parent, transport that changeset through email or something similar to email, and then apply it at the other end to get a different commit with similar but not identical metadata, as if via cherry-pick*).  You will just have to write your own tool, or use `git apply` and make the commit manually.

As the above paragraph suggests, one method you could use to write your own tool is to cherry-pick the merge (with `-m 1`) atop the first parent of the merge (probably on a detached HEAD), use `git format-patch` to format that patch, and use `git am` to apply that patch elsewhere.  This script is quite untested but might work:

```
#! /bin/sh

. $(git --exec-path)/git-sh-setup

# abort if on orphan branch (not worth the necessary hackery)
git rev-parse -q --verify HEAD 2>/dev/null ||
    die 'this does not work on an orphan branch'

# stolen out of git-filter-branch
finish_ident() {
    # Ensure non-empty id name.
    echo "case \"\$GIT_$1_NAME\" in \"\") GIT_$1_NAME=\"\${GIT_$1_EMAIL%%@*}\" && export GIT_$1_NAME;; esac"
    # And make sure everything is exported.
    echo "export GIT_$1_NAME"
    echo "export GIT_$1_EMAIL"
    echo "export GIT_$1_DATE"
}

set_ident () {
    parse_ident_from_commit author AUTHOR committer COMMITTER
    finish_ident AUTHOR
    finish_ident COMMITTER
}

# begin format-patch-even-if-merge code

hash=$(git rev-parse --verify "$1") || exit # verify that it's valid
hash=$(git rev-parse $hash^{commit}) || exit # and that it's a commit
parents=$(git rev-parse $hash^@)
set $parents

# if a root commit or ordinary commit, just use git format-patch
case $# in
0|1) git format-patch --stdout -1 $1; exit;;
*) ;; # merge - use cherry-pick
esac

# this is the meat of the trick, here
firstparent=$1
exec 3>&1 1>&2 # save stdout and redirect to stderr

echo "cherry picking $hash onto $firstparent to make it format-able"

# save where we were (branch or hash); arrange to return
# there on exit or ^C etc
if ! returnto=$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD 2>/dev/null); then
    # already detached, save hash ID
    returnto=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
fi
trap "git checkout $returnto; exit" 0 1 2 3 15

# Use the identity of the merge creator for new commits.
# NOTE: this should be optional and probably NOT the default,
# so it is commented out here.
#eval "$(set_ident <$hash)" ||
#    die "setting author/committer failed for commit $hash"

# Move to a detached head on the first parent of the merge.
git checkout $firstparent || exit

# Now we can cherry-pick the merge to a non-merge.
git cherry-pick -m 1 $hash || exit

# Now show the commit we just made, to original stdout.
git format-patch --stdout -1 HEAD 1>&3
```

#### A few more notes, just for completeness

If you wish to transport a merge commit intact, the easy way to do that is through the standard `git push` or `git fetch` protocols.  If those are not available for some reason, the `git bundle` command can make a file (which Git calls a *bundle*) that contains all the data needed to transport some portion of a repository across a barrier that push/fetch cannot itself cross.  You can then run `git fetch` on the bundle file, so that you extract the necessary information after crossing that barrier some other way.

Note, however, that you need *all* the objects reachable from the merge commit: the bundle must contain every object that the *other* Git *lacks*.  The whole point of the fetch and push commands is to let *Git* compute this set of objects: the two Gits talk to each other, to figure out what the sending Git has that the receiving Git lacks.  That's what goes into the bundle.  While it's OK for a bundle to have *extra* objects (the receiving Git can ignore them), it's a waste of resources to transport them, so fetch or push will compute the minimal object-set, pack it up into a "thin pack" (the fetch/push equivalent of a bundle), send it over the wire, and let the other end unpack it.

Comment: Validating the answer as it answers to the original question in a very complete way :).  I'll give a try to the cherry-pick solution and will update my post accordingly. Thx a lot for your help.