# git am: Patch format detection failed

Tags: git, patch, wine

I have never used patches with Git before and I need some help. I am trying to apply a patch to a Git repo to test a Wine patch, specifically [this patch here](https://bugs.winehq.org/attachment.cgi?id=60752). So I did the following:

```
$ git clone git://source.winehq.org/git/wine.git
$ cd wine
$ nano patch.p1
```

I then pasted the content of the patch with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>and used <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to save. Then I tried this:

```
$ git am patch.p1
Patch format detection failed.
```

What am I doing wrong? I have never applied a patch before.

Comment: `git am` applies patches that are mailbox-formatted. The one you linked to is not. You could use `git apply` on it. However, the code in the patch is quite nonsensical unless there's a reversed condition (shifting by negative counts produces undefined behavior).

Comment: @torek While [I am having trouble compiling Wine](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/430552/how-do-i-compile-wine-on-a-64-bit-ubuntu-system), `git apply` seems to have worked, as in it gives no errors. If you would like to post that comment to the patch creator: https://bugs.winehq.org/show_bug.cgi?id=44742

Comment: I don't have a login there, nor intend to create one unless I actually start using Wine. But: `+    if(MaskLength <= 32)
+        return ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER;
+    *Mask = 0xffffffff << ( 32 - MaskLength );` seems like the test should be `>=` not `<=`. 32-33 = -1 (or if unsigned, 0xffffffff), which is not a valid `<<` value. But I don't know what the intent of the function is.

Comment: my problem was, I had generated the patch in windows, and tried to apply in linux and it wouldn't work. I had to apply it in windows. I believe it had to do with the CRLF settings between the two OS/Git configs

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Patch format detection failed.` probably means you're using the wrong command: use `git apply` instead of `git am` or the other way around.

See [What is the difference between git am and git apply?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240154/what-is-the-difference-between-git-am-and-git-apply) for more on the difference between the 2.

Answer (score 6):

Use below command:
patch -p1 < patch_file_name.patch

- You will be asked to specify "File to patch", mention complete path /
- Assume -R [n]: n
- Apply anyway? [n]: y

Do for all files present in you patch.

- If any merge conflict occurs then check the conflict in ".rej" file which has 
  been generated and resolve & apply those changes.
- do "git add " and "commit" your changes.