# git am: Patch format detection failed. git apply also fails

Tags: git, git-patch, git-am, git-apply

I'm trying to learn git patching, so I set up a test repo and made a few commits.

I then created a patch: `git format-patch -1 HEAD --stdout > changes.patch`

Next, I checked out a new branch and tried to use changes.patch: `git am .\changes.patch`.  It gives me the error `Patch format detection failed.`

I searched here, and found [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49313250/git-am-patch-format-detection-failed).

So I tried `git apply .\changes.patch`.  It gives me `error: unrecognized input`.

The patch file seems fine to my untrained eye:

```
From 1c054c05bc528afbd929a1744fcacf9d70069246 Mon Sep 17 00:00:00 2001
From: MyUsername <my.email@gmail.com>
Date: Sat, 4 May 2019 22:43:32 -0400
Subject: [PATCH] Commit 4

---
test.txt | 3 ++-
1 file changed, 2 insertions(+), 1 deletion(-)

diff --git a/test.txt b/test.txt
index 58ef11d..763fe4e 100644
--- a/test.txt
+++ b/test.txt
@@ -1,3 +1,4 @@
 Initial commit
 Commit 2
-Commit 3
\ No newline at end of file
+Commit 3
+Commit 4
\ No newline at end of file
-- 
2.21.0.windows.1
```

I thought it might be that the patch is in the same directory as the repo, so I moved it to another directory.  The results are the same.

I also noticed that many people had a `<` in the command, so I tried it: `git am < ..\changes.patch`.  Apparently that's not valid syntax.

This is using 64 bit git on Windows with PowerShell.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `cat .\changes.patch | git am`.

But I have no idea why `git am .\changes.patch` can't work.

Update:

`changes.patch` is in `USC-2 Little Endian` by default. After changing it to `UTF-8`, `git am .\changes.patch` works.

Comment: Interesting.  It did work!  I'll try to see if I can find out why that is.

Comment: @Danation after some research, I find it's caused by the encoding of `changes.patch`. Powershell generates the patch in `USC-2 Little Endian`.  After changing it to `UTF-8`, `git am .\changes.patch` works.

Comment: Nice to have the mystery solved!  I thought it was strange that I'd have this encoding issue, so I searched around more.  According to this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751617/1192877, the culprit is `--stdout` and how PowerShell handles the output.  I tried it out, and it's true: without `--stdout` the resulting file works properly.

Comment: Is it UCS-2, or UTF-16-LE? (The difference is that UCS-2 does not allow surrogate escapes.)

Comment: @torek Notepad++ tells that it’s USC-2 Little Endian.

Comment: @torek And `file changes.patch` prints `Little-endian UTF-16 Unicode text, with CRLF, CR line terminators`.

Comment: So, the way to tell which it really is would be to ask PowerShell to write a file with Unicode characters that require surrogate escapes to be used, and see whether they are.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to create a patch from `HEAD`? Then you can simply do as follows:

To save the patch:

```
git show HEAD > /some/location/patch.txt
```

To apply the patch:

```
git apply /some/location/patch.txt
```

If you want to create a patch from a bunch of commits you can do:

```
git diff OLDEST_COMMIT..NEWEST_COMMIT > /some/location/patch.txt
```

This way you can, for instance, create a patch containing the changes from a feature branch:

```
git diff origin/master...origin/new_feature > /some/location/feature.patch
```

Notice the three dots, they mean you want the changes contained in `origin/new_feature` with respect to the *common ancestor* of the two branches.

Comment: My goal is to learn how to use `git format-patch` and `git am` for a particular project that requires collaboration through email.  In this case I was just using HEAD as a test case.

Comment: If you want to send the patches as attachments, you can do it this way. You can share this files in any way you want.

Comment: The thing I like about `git am` is that it preserves the commit history of the contributor.  As I understand it, `git apply` acts as if the receiver is the author.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't familiar with git format-patch / git am. I occasionally use `git apply` and don't need those additional information. Good to know.