# Applying patch doesn't create newly created files in Git

Tags: git, patch

I have created a new file called `ABC.txt` in branch **x**. I didn't commit the changes.

Then I wanted to move these changes into a new branch called **y**. So I followed these steps:

1. `$ git diff > mypatch.diff`
2. `$ git clean -fd`
3. `$ git checkout y`
4. `$ git apply myPatch.diff`
   `error: ABC.txt: No such file or directory`

Why git can't simply create my new ABC.txt file in the current branch I'm in?

Comment: For future reference, what you were trying to do can be done with `git stash`.  Or, in most cases, you could just do the checkout while keeping the change in your work tree and/or index (and git would warn you if this was going to be a problem).

Answer (score 7):

That is because `git diff` only lists changes of files that are part of the repository, and your newly created file is not.

The easiest solution is to add the file to the index:

```
$ git add ABC.txt
```

And then use the `--cached` option when creating the patch:

```
$ git diff --cached > mypatch.diff
```

However if the error happens when you apply the diff, it may be caused because the file does not exist in the target branch, so `git` does not know where to apply those changes.

You can see if the diff file contains changes to an formerly existing file, or a newly created file, by looking at the chunk header:

If you see:

```
--- a/ABC.txt
+++ b/ABC.txt
```

Then there are changes to an existing file. Applying this patch will not create a new file from void.

But if you see:

```
--- /dev/null
+++ b/ABC.txt
```

Then it is a newly created file and applying this patch will create a new file with these contents.

Comment: When I look at `mypatch.diff` file I can see that the newly created file content is also there.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan: Ah, but then it is probably not a new file. I mean the diff includes only a few changes in the file because that file already existed, but it does not exist in branch `y` so there is nowhere to apply those changes.

Comment: @JudeNiroshan: If that is the case, either you need to do `git diff <oldercommit>`, being `<oldercommit>` a commit before the file was created or just copy `ABC.txt` file manually.

Answer (score 2):

When I followed these steps:

```
git add ABC.txt
git diff --cached > mypatch.diff
```

mypatch.diff contained my new files, but none of my edited files.

Here's what worked for me:

```
git add -N ABC.txt
git diff > mypatch.diff
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```sh
$git am foo.patch
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12240154/what-is-the-difference-between-git-am-and-git-apply)