# How to create and apply git patches between two identical repos with mismatching commit IDs

Tags: git, patch

I shallow-cloned a git repo from GitHub and moved it to an isolated private gitlab server. In order to push the shallow clone to the new repo, I had to lose the commit IDs and tags (I used this answer: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50996201/13172341)).

Now I want to create git patches externally and moved them to the private gitlab server in order to keep the private project updated. But I understand that git patches rely on persistent commit SHAs to work - And the commits SHAs in the two projects do not match.

Is there a way for me to create usable patches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I understand that git patches rely on persistent commit SHAs to work

Yes, if you are using [`git am`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am) to apply the patches generated by [`git format-patch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch) (as [seen here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/git/how-to-generate-a-git-patch-for-a-specific-commit.html#generating-patch-files-for-the-given-range-of-commits-9))

```
git format-patch <first-commit-hash>^..<end-commit-hash>
```

But if you are using [`git apply`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply), you should be able to apply those path to your current working directory, without checking for the right SHA1.
See "[What is the difference between `git am` and `git apply`?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12240235/6309)".