# How do you control the order in which files appear in a GitHub gist

Tags: github, gist

Is there a way to control the order in which files appear in a gist? They don't seem to be alphabetical or chronological. I'd like to have a README.md appear as the first file in [a multi-file gist](https://gist.github.com/Sinetheta/6003037), but no amount of "deleting" a file and re-adding it seems to change anything.

Is there an order to these files that I'm not seeing, or does GitHub maintain an internal filetype priority list?

Comment: My upvote counted as `100` how cool!

Comment: I just created a github community feedback asking to be able to manually change the order of the files without having to change the name of each so they are sorted in asciibetical order. That's not what the feedback is mainly about, but I also ask for that. If you are interested, please upvote it. Here it is: https://github.com/orgs/community/discussions/86555

Answer (score 130, accepted):

Since at least 2018, the order is [alphabetical, with periods and numbers coming before letters.](https://github.com/isaacs/github/issues/195)

That is, as mentioned in [Andrew D.Bond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3442232/andrew-d-bond)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61832468/6309):

1. `$`
2. `.` (dot)
3. Numbers
4. Leading space (although the space doesn't appear after saving, the sort order is still updated)
   (although bis, in Sept. 2020, [IvanaGyro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6663588/ivanagyro) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17665267/how-do-you-control-the-order-in-which-files-appear-in-a-github-gist/17668995?noredirect=1#comment112988123_17668995) leading spaces will not affect the order any more)
5. `_` (underscore)
6. Letters (case insensitive)

Around 2013-2014 a [different order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCIIbetical_order) was used. See [Andrew D. Bond](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3442232/andrew-d-bond)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61832468/6309) for more.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I've never really thought of "case" when considering sort order.

Comment: @Barney strange, it was working for me. That should be answered by Github support then: https://github.com/contact

Comment: @Barney I just [forked your repo](https://gist.github.com/Sinetheta/6510464) and it seems to be working. Which rule of ASCIIbetical is not being applied? Yes, Uppercase before Lower, but when the same case [L before R](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5XEN4vtH4Ic).

Comment: @Sinetheta you're absolutely right — I don't know how I managed to screw that up but when I try now it's fine. I retract all the above and I've updated the Gist team at GitHub.

Comment: i wish i could order my own files

Comment: @ConnorLeech well, you can, after a fashion: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20949455/6309

Comment: This answer is wrong and/or out-of-date: [`URL.cgi` is listed after both `hiawatha-url.conf.include` and `example.url`](https://gist.github.com/b845f0f9f06cb0db42918107e9eda18c/463d3054a533e7d042aab469475a045aeac71c8c). So if ASCIIbetical really implies caps trump lowercase, it's definitely NOT being used.

Comment: @JamesTheAwesomeDude I agree. I have edited my 5-years old answer: the order seems more alphabetical now.

Comment: It seems that adding leading spaces will not affect the order any more (2020.09.15).

Comment: @IvanaGyro Thank you for this feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Note to self: 300th Great Answer gold badge, a bit [more than 31 months](https://www.timeanddate.com/date/durationresult.html?d1=15&m1=05&y1=2018&d2=27&m2=12&y2=2020) after the [200th Great Answer gold badge](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2250170/6309).

Comment: It's 2021 and I still can't manually reorder my own files!

Answer (score 16):

They are ordered automatically by name, following the [ASCII table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Printable_characters).

Unfortunatly, right now, it is not possible to order them by dragging, but there is a trick. You can control the order by adding one or more spaces before the name. The space will not be shown after editing, but the order will change.

E.g: lets say we have 3 files with the automatic order:

- AFile.java
- Readme.md
- SomeFile.txt

We can invert the order by putting spaces like this:

- (space)(space)SomeFile.txt
- (space)Readme.md
- AFile.txt

Comment: I can't get this to work. I've added spaces to the beginning of the title name,
and it doesn't seem to affect the order.  I'm trying to mark "part 1 and part 2" as the first file(notebook) of the list of files within this repository. 

https://github.com/moondra2017/Python-Regular-Expressions

Comment: @Moondra The question is talking about ordering gists. That are normal github files

Comment: @MarioVelasco  I see. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: This workaround (if it ever worked) is broken. Adding spaces to the front of a filename is ineffectual.

Comment: I ended up using dashes control this. And since the filename `README.md` doesn't have any major effect (except the `.md` extension), I just name the file the title that I'd like to use for the gist, e.g. `- How to Foo Bar.md`. That way not only does it show up first, but the main title is more descriptive. For example: https://gist.github.com/patricknelson/57ae24986cb13613314fb1f3c00a95d7

Comment: Spaces still seem to work if pushing edits from a git clone of the gist, but it seems that editing the gist from the GitHub GUI will strip out leading spaces. So still kinda works, but fragile (only if you're willing to edit from a local clone, and perhaps subject to future changes/prohibitions on GitHub's part).

Answer (score 13):

As mentioned by @VonC in his answer, the order is asciibetical. Quick solution would be to prefix all files with numbers indicating the order in which you wish the files to appear, example 0_, 1_, 2_, ... 9_. Note, this solution will not work beyond 9 files as 10_ will appear before 2_. In that case, two digits need to be used 00_, 01_, 02_, ..., 09_, 10_, 11_, ... This can be generalized to any number of digits in the number of files. Although, it seems less likely, to me, that more more than 10 files to be shared in a gist.

Comment: this answer has the actual solution. i.e to add preceding zeroes after 9 files

Comment: Meh...I'd call it a workaround

Answer (score 13):

Updating my answer from an earlier year with additional testing I did just now:

Github automatically sorts files in a gist according to:

1. `#`
2. `$`
3. `.` (period)
4. Numbers
5. `_` (underscore)
6. Letters (case insensitive)

Leading spaces are dropped.

If additional characters' sort order is discovered, feel free to edit this answer.

(Added this answer because even after I improved another answer to this question last year, I still couldn't find the sort order of special characters anywhere.)