# How to change the code for Scipy SLSQP Fortran code and test it?

Tags: python, numpy, debugging, optimization, scipy

Here is the issue:

I found a bug of Scipy SLSQP algorithm in developing my project. I post the issue to Scipy community to discuss with the developers and they gave me some ideas. Here is the discussion: https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7618. 
Now what they supposed is to change some of the basic Fortran code of SLSQP algorithm and test it with some larger-scale problem instead of some toy examples. I can test it with my project, but the problem is I can't find the Fortran code of SLSQP on my computer. Can anyone tell me how can I change the code and test it like what the developer's has done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the most recent code with the fix:

   git clone https://github.com/scipy/scipy.git
2. Apply the patch from [the issue](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/compare/master...pv:slsqp-incons-fix.patch) to the code. Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249852/how-can-i-apply-a-patch) on how to do it.
3. Build updated package. Instructions are [here](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/linux.html).
4. Link it to your project and run tests!