# petalinux project build failing with m4-native-1.4.18-r0 do_compile failed on host Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: yocto, xilinx, ubuntu-20.04, petalinux

While trying to port petalinux 2018.3 project compiling Ubuntu 16 host  to Ubuntu 20 host.
Following error is occurring

```
  ERROR: m4-native-1.4.18-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at .
       .
       .
       .
    | gcc   -I. -I../../m4-1.4.18/lib   -isystem/home/os-bsp-team/fadil/2018.3/projects/rrh_4.0/RRH_TRX_MULTI_ADI_MULTICH/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include  -isystem/home/os-bsp-team/fadil/2018.3/projects/rrh_4.0/RRH_TRX_MULTI_ADI_MULTICH/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o freadahead.o ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/freadahead.c
    | gcc   -I. -I../../m4-1.4.18/lib   -isystem/home/os-bsp-team/fadil/2018.3/projects/rrh_4.0/RRH_TRX_MULTI_ADI_MULTICH/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include  -isystem/home/os-bsp-team/fadil/2018.3/projects/rrh_4.0/RRH_TRX_MULTI_ADI_MULTICH/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/include -O2 -pipe -c -o fseeko.o ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/fseeko.c
    | ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/fseeko.c: In function ‘rpl_fseeko’:
    | ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/fseeko.c:110:4: error: #error "Please port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform! Look at the code in fseeko.c, then report this to bug-gnulib."
    |   110 |   #error "Please port gnulib fseeko.c to your platform! Look at the code in fseeko.c, then report this to bug-gnulib."
    |       |    ^~~~~
    | ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/freadahead.c: In function ‘freadahead’:
    | ../../m4-1.4.18/lib/freadahead.c:92:3: error: #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
    |    92 |  #error "Please port gnulib freadahead.c to your platform! Look at the definition of fflush, fread, ungetc on your system, then report this to bug-gnulib."
    |       |   ^~~~~
    | make[3]: *** [Makefile:1915: fseeko.o] Error 1
    | make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
    | make[3]: *** [Makefile:1915: freadahead.o] Error 1
    | make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/os-bsp-team/fadil/2018.3/projects/rrh_4.0/RRH_TRX_MULTI_ADI_MULTICH/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build/lib'
    | make[2]: *** [Makefile:1674: all] Error 2
    | make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/os-bsp-team/fadil/2018.3/projects/rrh_4.0/RRH_TRX_MULTI_ADI_MULTICH/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build/lib'
    | make[1]: *** [Makefile:1572: all-recursive] Error 1
    | make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/os-bsp-team/fadil/2018.3/projects/rrh_4.0/RRH_TRX_MULTI_ADI_MULTICH/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/build'
    | make: *** [Makefile:1528: all] Error 2
    | ERROR: oe_runmake failed
    | WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
    | ERROR: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /home/os-bsp-team/fadil/2018.3/projects/rrh_4.0/RRH_TRX_MULTI_ADI_MULTICH/build/tmp/work/x86_64-linux/m4-native/1.4.18-r0/temp/log.do_compile.1545563)
    ERROR: Task (/home/os-bsp-team/fadil/2018.3/components/yocto/source/aarch64/layers/core/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4-native_1.4.18.bb:do_compile) failed with exit code '1'
    NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 894 tasks of which 878 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.
```

By googling found this patch need to be applied http://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/commit/meta/recipes-devtools/m4?h=thud&id=95ca077ab871ceff46c2052f324f879a1d624ff4 Can someone please help to figure out this issue and apply this patch in yocto.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the patch with git like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249852/how-to-apply-a-patch-generated-with-git-format-patch).

Or you can download the  [m4-1.4.18-glibc-change-work-around.patch](https://git.yoctoproject.org/cgit/cgit.cgi/poky/tree/meta/recipes-devtools/m4/m4/m4-1.4.18-glibc-change-work-around.patch?h=thud&id=95ca077ab871ceff46c2052f324f879a1d624ff4) and place it in a `files` subfolder in `meta/recipes-devtools/m4/files` and add add the following line to `SRC_URI`:

```
SRC_URI = "${GNU_MIRROR}/m4/m4-${PV}.tar.gz \
        file://ac_config_links.patch \
        file://remove-gets.patch \
        file://m4-1.4.18-glibc-change-work-around.patch \
        "
```

`file://m4-1.4.18-glibc-change-work-around.patch` in SRC_URI will apply the patch for you.

You can also look for the location of `remove-gets.patch`and place this patch in the same folder.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, But this issue is not getting resolved, by above steps. I tried to apply patch as you mentioned and no change in o/p. Is it possible to run yocto poky on ubuntu 20??

Comment: can you confirm that the patch was applied?

Comment: yes , patch was getting applied. I had to move the entire petalinux project to Ubuntu 14 and it is working fine there. Thank you Maik for support

Answer (score 0):

In my case the patch applied as suggested by Maik Nassauer helped.

Go to folder:
yocto-2.4-fus/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/m4

Edit file "m4-1.4.18.inc" and change SRC_URI
from:

```
SRC_URI += "file://ac_config_links.patch \
            file://remove-gets.patch \
           "
```

to:

```
SRC_URI += "file://ac_config_links.patch \
            file://remove-gets.patch \
            file://m4-1.4.18-glibc-change-work-around.patch \
           "
```

Go to subfolder m4 and place patch "m4-1.4.18-glibc-change-work-around.patch" there, next to other patches.