# How to automate pulling from a repository with GitHub Rest API in Python?

Tags: python, github, github-api

My goal is to automatically pull from a private github repository every time a change is pushed to the master branch, but I'm not sure how I should go about this.

Comment: Create a webhook and process the push event.

Answer (score 1):

check this docs about [github api pulls](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/pulls)

example command

```sh
curl \
  -H "Accept: application/vnd.github.v3+json" \
  https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/hello-world/pulls
```

if the status is 200 then you will get a json response with metadata:

```json
[
  {
    "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347",
    "id": 1,
    "node_id": "MDExOlB1bGxSZXF1ZXN0MQ==",
    "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1347",
    "diff_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1347.diff",
    "patch_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1347.patch",
    "issue_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347",
    "commits_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347/commits",
    "review_comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/1347/comments",
    "review_comment_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/pulls/comments{/number}",
    "comments_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/1347/comments",
    "statuses_url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/statuses/6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
    "number": 1347,

....
```

i guess from here you need to apply the diffs and the patches manually (using git ofcouse)

```
    "diff_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1347.diff",
    "patch_url": "https://github.com/octocat/Hello-World/pull/1347.patch",
```

to apply the patch using git, check this [stack-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2249852/how-to-apply-a-patch-generated-with-git-format-patch)

to do that in python, you need to use `requests` library and call `git` as `subprocess command`